# Is it possible to use dot env with next export?

Tags: next.js, dotenv

I have a NextJS app with a NodeJS backend (azure function). The NextJS app is statically exported but is it possible to use dot-env with next export?

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that because `.env` files are ignored in all kind of build processes

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? It's perfectly possible to use `.env` files when statically exporting a Next.js app.

Comment: yes , in build process the data inside `.env` file is used to get export , but the file it self is no included in the build version of the project